# MySQL ORDER BY columns across multiple joined tables

Tags: mysql, index, join, order-by

I have a database which consists of three tables, with the following structure:

**restaurant table:** restaurant_id, location_id, rating. **Example:** 1325, 77, 4.5

**restaurant_name table:** restaurant_id, language, name. **Example:** 1325, 'en', 'Pizza Express'

**location_name table:** location_id, language, name. **Example:** 77, 'en', 'New York'

I would like to get the restaurant info in English, sorted by location name and restaurant name, and use the LIMIT clause to paginate the result. So my SQL is:

```
SELECT ln.name, rn.name
FROM restaurant r
INNER JOIN location_name ln
ON r.location_id = ln.location_id
AND ln.language = 'en'
INNER JOIN restaurant_name rn
ON r.restaurant_id = rn.restaurant_id
AND rn.language = 'en'
ORDER BY ln.name, rn.name
LIMIT 0, 50
```

This is terribly slow - so I refined my SQL with deferred JOIN, which make things a lot faster (from over 10 seconds to 2 seconds):

```
SELECT ln.name, rn.name
FROM restaurant r
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT r.restaurant_id
    FROM restaurant r
    INNER JOIN location_name ln
    ON r.location_id = ln.location_id
    AND ln.language = 'en'
    INNER JOIN restaurant_name rn
    ON r.restaurant_id = rn.restaurant_id
    AND rn.language = 'en'
    ORDER BY ln.name, rn.name
    LIMIT 0, 50
) r1
ON r.restaurant_id = r1.restaurant_id
INNER JOIN location_name ln
ON r.location_id = ln.location_id
AND ln.language = 'en'
INNER JOIN restaurant_name rn
ON r.restaurant_id = rn.restaurant_id
AND rn.language = 'en'
ORDER BY ln.name, rn.name
```

2 seconds is unfortunately still not very acceptable to the user, so I go and check the EXPLAIN of the my query, and it appears that the slow part is on the ORDER BY clause, which I see "Using temporary; Using filesort". I checked the official reference manual about [ORDER BY optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/order-by-optimization.html#order-by-index-use) and I come across this statement:

> In some cases, MySQL cannot use indexes to resolve the ORDER BY,
>   although it may still use indexes to find the rows that match the
>   WHERE clause. Examples:
>
> The query joins many tables, and the columns in the ORDER BY are not
>   all from the first nonconstant table that is used to retrieve rows.
>   (This is the first table in the EXPLAIN output that does not have a
>   const join type.)

So for my case, given that the two columns I'm ordering by are from the nonconstant joined tables, index cannot be used. **My question is, is there any other approach I can take to speed things up, or what I've done so far is already the best I can achieve?** Must I move the columns I wanna sort back to the primary table? (But my site actually offers multiple ways to sort the data, so I'll have to eventually move 6 to 7 columns, causing a lot of data redundancy...)

---

Below are the DDL of the table. I built them for illustrating this problem only, the real table has much more columns.

```
CREATE TABLE restaurant (
  restaurant_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  location_id INT NOT NULL,
  rating INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (restaurant_id),
  INDEX idx_restaurant_1 (location_id)
);

CREATE TABLE restaurant_name (
  restaurant_id INT NOT NULL,
  language VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  INDEX idx_restaurant_name_1 (restaurant_id, language),
  INDEX idx_restaurant_name_2 (name)
);

CREATE TABLE location_name (
  location_id INT NOT NULL,
  language VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  INDEX idx_location_name_1 (location_id, language),
  INDEX idx_location_name_2 (name)
);
```

Below is the EXPLAIN output with the ORDER BY clause:

```
+----+-------------+------------+--------+--------------------------+-----------------------+---------+--------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type   | possible_keys            | key                   | key_len | ref                            | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+--------------------------+-----------------------+---------+--------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL    | NULL                     | NULL                  | NULL    | NULL                           |   50 |                                              |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | rn         | ref    | idx_restaurant_name_1    | idx_restaurant_name_1 | 1538    | r1.restaurant_id,const,const   |    1 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | r          | eq_ref | PRIMARY,idx_restaurant_1 | PRIMARY               | 4       | r1.restaurant_id               |    1 |                                              |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | ln         | ref    | idx_location_name_1      | idx_location_name_1   | 1538    | test.r.location_id,const,const |    1 | Using where                                  |
|  2 | DERIVED     | rn         | ALL    | idx_restaurant_name_1    | NULL                  | NULL    | NULL                           | 8484 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DERIVED     | r          | eq_ref | PRIMARY,idx_restaurant_1 | PRIMARY               | 4       | test.rn.restaurant_id          |    1 |                                              |
|  2 | DERIVED     | ln         | ref    | idx_location_name_1      | idx_location_name_1   | 1538    | test.r.location_id             |    1 | Using where                                  |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+--------------------------+-----------------------+---------+--------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Below is the EXPLAIN output without the ORDER BY clause:

```
+----+-------------+------------+--------+--------------------------+-----------------------+---------+--------------------------------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type   | possible_keys            | key                   | key_len | ref                            | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+--------------------------+-----------------------+---------+--------------------------------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL    | NULL                     | NULL                  | NULL    | NULL                           |   50 |                          |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | rn         | ref    | idx_restaurant_name_1    | idx_restaurant_name_1 | 1538    | r1.restaurant_id,const,const   |    1 | Using where              |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | r          | eq_ref | PRIMARY,idx_restaurant_1 | PRIMARY               | 4       | r1.restaurant_id               |    1 |                          |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | ln         | ref    | idx_location_name_1      | idx_location_name_1   | 1538    | test.r.location_id,const,const |    1 | Using where              |
|  2 | DERIVED     | rn         | index  | idx_restaurant_name_1    | idx_restaurant_name_1 | 1538    | NULL                           | 8484 | Using where; Using index |
|  2 | DERIVED     | r          | eq_ref | PRIMARY,idx_restaurant_1 | PRIMARY               | 4       | test.rn.restaurant_id          |    1 |                          |
|  2 | DERIVED     | ln         | ref    | idx_location_name_1      | idx_location_name_1   | 1538    | test.r.location_id             |    1 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+--------------------------+-----------------------+---------+--------------------------------+------+--------------------------+
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I see "over-normalization" as the main problem.

The focus for this query seems to be on "language", yet that is the last thing checked.

For one attempt at a solution, let's rearrange the schema to these two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE restaurant_attributes (
  restaurant_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  rating INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (restaurant_id),
);

CREATE TABLE restaurants_by_lang (
  restaurant_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  language VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL CHARACTER SET ascii,  -- see note
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  location VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(language, restaurant_id),
  INDEX (language, location, name),  -- perfect for the query
  INDEX (name),
  INDEX (location)
);
```

Now the query is simply:

```
SELECT location, name
    FROM restaurants_by_lang
    WHERE language = 'en'
    ORDER BY location, name
    LIMIT 0, 50;
```

This schema will even allow for efficient "pagination", which will be your next problem.  (See [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination).)

I will suggest that if you have a million restaurants, listing the first 50 by location is a next-to-useless UI design.  I recommend re-thinking the need for the query.  For example, instead of paginating through the entire list, I suggest some form of drill-down such as country to state to city/area to restaurants.  It will be a lot faster for the user to find Zahir's in Zimbabwe.

But... Since I can't see the rest of your `SELECTs`, I don't know what other things I may have made worse for some of them.

I picked a 5-char language based on a standard for such.  Do not use 255 unless you really need such.

**Testing**

When testing with less data than you will eventually have, this technique is often handy...

```
FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT ...;
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
```

Then look at the numbers.  A number that approximates the number of rows in the table (or some multiple thereof) indicates a table scan(s).  Some number that approximates the `LIMIT` value indicates that the query could whittle down the task efficiently.

I claim you will see '50' with my approach, and at least 7K (20K?) from your approach.

Note:  Page 4 (with `LIMIT 150, 50`) would say 200 for mine; yours will not change.  With the technique in my pagination link, even page 4 will be only 50.

Each temp table (due to `GROUP BY` and/or `ORDER BY`) will show `Handler_write` indicating the number of rows (times the number of tmp tables).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57765/discussion-on-answer-by-rick-james-mysql-order-by-columns-across-multiple-joined).